# GOOGLE SEARCH FROM TEXTVIEW IN ANDROID STUDIO 2.3.3

Tags: android, textview

I want to google search the text on the TextView of my android application. The text is more than a single word  hence making the url seems tough with each word seperated by a + .I tried storing it in a string and using intent but the words are not in themselves a a url and that method fails as well. Suppose the words are "HELLO AND WELCOME". Please suggest a method to search on google "HELLO AND WELCOME".
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get this straight. You want someone to use your app, type in a EditText, and when they click a button, it takes them to a browser and searches for the words they typed in?

XML

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //https://www.google.com/#q=
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, textView.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/#q=" + textView.getText())));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am applying OCR to iamges and then the extracted text is dispayed in a textview. Now i want the text from textview to be searched on the browser.

Comment: do you want the user to click on the textview? from that action, load browser and search?

Comment: yes exactly. I need to google search whatever the text is there in the textview.

Comment: So can you suggest me the write logic or the code? @Droidev

Comment: No problem. glad I could help. Hit the up arrow and the star.